# APDU Write block commands on mifare classic

Tags: nfc, mifare, apdu

I have been trying to write some data to my mifare classic cards. first I send  these two commands which returns 90 00:

**Load Mifare Keys:**

> FF 82 20 01 06 FF FF FF FF FF FF

**Authenticate:**

> FF 86 00 00 05 01 00 01 60 01

now I can write commands to sector 0 and block 1 + 2

> ff d6 00 01 10 14 01 03 E1 03 E1 03 E1 03 E1 03 E1 03 E1 03 E1
>
> ff d6 00 02 10 03 E1 03 E1 03 E1 03 E1 03 E1 03 E1 03 E1 03 E1

i mistakenly overwritten block 3  a few times rendering this sector unreadable it seems:

if I send the command
ff d6 00 04 10   I get return error 69 82 which i googled as authentication error

do I need to authenticate to every sector? if so what is the command to  do this for the next and following sectors?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

yes, You have to authenticate every sector before read/write on the block of that sector.Now you have execute Authentication command and you overwrite the block 3(sector trailer) that means the keys and access right has been change.

**APDU For Authenticate a Block:-**

The APDU format for Authenticate a block should be in following format.

> CLA+  INS+    P1+ P2+ Lc+ (Version + AddMSB + AddLSB + KeyID + KeyNumber)

**For Example :-**

CLA = FF

INS = 86

P1  = 00

P2  = 01    (Block Number for Authentication)

Lc  = 05                (Length of Data Field)

Data Field = Version + AddMSB + AddLSB + KeyId + KeyNumber

Version=01

AddMSB=00

AddLSB=05        (Block Number)

KeyID=60/61     (60 for keyA and 61 for keyB)

KeyNo= 00         (Key Slot number of reader)

> FF    86  00  00  05  01 00 05 60 00

Comment: thanks vikky, I actually allready saw your post on the other question after i post this

Comment: would you please provide the reference for the full list of specs ?

Comment: you can download the document for reference from https://www.acs.com.hk/en/products/3/acr122u-usb-nfc-reader/