# how to write a data to the mifare classic tag

Tags: c, nfc, mifare, apdu

I am working on NFC (Mifare classic tag). I want to know how to write data to the mi fare classic tag. I have empty Tag. Please tell the APDU commands which I need to use for mifare classic tag.

I am sending APDU commands as follows :

```
\x00','\xA4', '\x04', '\x00','\x07','\xd2','\x76','\x00','\x00','\x85','\x01','\x00
```

If I am using this apdu command s its not giving any success response (as every APDU commands will have 9000) its going into the else part. Please tell me the correct apdu commands. I am writing code into the C language. The reader I have is MFC 523. What are steps need to follow?

```
// code i am using its for the Mobile POS 

   int ret;
   sendtoUSB("going to the auth",17); // for display purpose 
   // for authentication we will use the basic  authentication between the reader and writer 
      Sys_ClearScreen();
      char cRecvBuf[128];
      int  i,j;      
      char cSendBuf[10]= {0xFF,0x86,0x00,0x00,0x05,0x01,0x00,0x05,0x60,0x01};     // authenticaton key 
      char msg[128];
      u32  rlen; // response length 
      Sys_PcdOpen();
      while(1)
      {
          sendtoUSB("in while",8);
          if(Sys_Kbhit()==KEY_CANCEL)
             break;

          ret = Sys_PiccPresent();

          // activation of the NFC
          ret = Sys_PiccActivate();


          uchar key[16]= {0xFF,0x82,0x20,0x01,0x06,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF} ; //Load keys command 

          char cSendBuf[10]= {0xFF,0x86,0x00,0x00,0x05,0x01,0x00,0x05,0x60,0x01};   // authentication command 

          ret = Sys_PiccCommand(key,11,&rlen,cRecvBuf); // sending the command 
          sendtoUSB("In send cmd",11);

          sendtoUSB(key,strlen(key)); // here i am getting the key as i am sending 


          sendtoUSB(cRecvBuf,rlen);  // in recvbuf i am agetting as 6E00



          if(ret==0) // checking the returing value 
          {
              // its coming into the if also 
              sendtoUSB("sucess",6);
              if(rlen>=0)
              {
                 if((cRecvBuf[rlen-2]==0x90) && (cRecvBuf[rlen-1]==0x00)) // checking the 90 00 response 

                 {
                      // not coming here
                      sendtoUSB("in if",5); 
                    strcpy(msg, "ankita"); 
                    for(i=0;i<rlen-2;i++)
                      sprintf(msg+strlen(msg), "%02X", cRecvBuf[i]);

                    Sys_DisplayLine( 2, msg, 0, ALIGN_LEFT) ;

                 }
                 else
                 {
                     // its coming here 

                    sendtoUSB("In else",7);



                    sprintf(msg, "In else 02X%02X", cRecvBuf[rlen-2],cRecvBuf[rlen-1]);


                    Sys_DisplayLine( 2, msg, 1, ALIGN_CENTER) ;
                    sendtoUSB ("fail data",9);
                    sendtoUSB(cRecvBuf,rlen);
                    sendtoUSB(msg,strlen(msg));

                }
            }

        }
        Sys_PiccDeselect(RM_WAIT);
        break;
    }
    Sys_PcdClose();
    Sys_WaitReturn();

    Sys_Buzzer(KB_BEEP_DURATION);



}


// i am following the same steps for the authentication also


//open NFC
// check NFC is there or not 
//activate 
// send command
```

Comment: What status word return from this command.

Comment: @vikky thanku you so much vikky u give me reply...

Comment: @vikky i am getting the response as 6E00 class error i am getting

Comment: @vikky please tell me what the mistake i am doing. i given authentication keys also

Comment: From where you get this command.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957538/apdu-write-block-commands-on-mifare-classic

Comment: 6E00 means "Error in class byte(CLA)"

Comment: i got this from the datasheet which my PM given me....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957538/apdu-write-block-commands-on-mifare-classic yesterday only i saw this post vikky i tried also with that but same response i am getting...(6E00) and i am using tag (mifare classic, mifare desfire) and my reader is MFC523

Comment: can you post some code here

Comment: @vikky i share the code vikky. for the APDU commands its cominf response as the 6E00  i am sending the commands as u have mentioned

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61322/discussion-between-vikky-and-user3409183).

Answer (score 1):

I think, there is problem in "Load Key command". Here I am posting the Load key command structure.

[image]

Comment: after this in the authentication i am getting the problem

Comment: So what was the problem?

Comment: authentication APDu commands is going into fail condition. and in loading key APDU command also its giving same response. (6E00). i already mentioned in the chat

Comment: i am also not getting now what is may be the problem. thatsy  i am asking u. n i am having ISO 14443 standard... so for that also APDU will b e different or same  ???i search also.. but i am i m getting the same response. is it problem with APDU or some other issue...

Comment: Have you check this code with other "MFC 523".May be there is an issue with reader.Have you any specification of reader.

Comment: for Mifare classic 1k card we wont get any ATS.i am gettin gthe answer to request as 04 and SAK (select ACknowledge) is as 080D http://nfc-tools.org/index.php?title=ISO14443A i refer this link check that once again

Comment: No, Every card has ATR or ATS.

Comment: http://nfc-tools.org/index.php?title=ISO14443A u can check this link once.... i have mifare classic 1k card

Comment: okk i didnt check that :( i am sorry ... i will check n telll yuo

Comment: hi vikky i tried with that command also.. now today i got know that classic card wont card with that reader. only desfire will work. so do u have any idea with that

Comment: Hi Angel..:P,Means you want to know about desfire card?Am I right?

Comment: hiii...:P :P.....yea want to know @ the desfire card...and the steps for reading and reading and writing data to the card

Comment: Hmm...Have you desfire datasheet?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending authentication ADPU command in this format? If not, then try the following. It is working for me in MIFARE Classic tags authentication.

```
GENERAL AUTHENTICATE command APDU

    CLA     INS     P1      P2      Lc      DATAin          Le
    0xFF    h86     00      00      05      seebelow        -
    (def.)  (for 
            authent-
            ication 
            cmmd)

            GENERAL AUTHENTICATE Data In bytes

    Byte 0          Byte 1          Byte2           Byte3           Byte4
    h01             h00             Block            key            key     
                                    number          location        index
                                                    or Key 
                                                    type
```

The block number (BYTE 2) is the address on the card, where we try to be authenticated (block no.)

The key location or Key type (BYTE 3) must be either:

- h60 for authentication using a CRYPTO1 “A” key (standard PC/SC-defined value),
- h61 for authentication using a CRYPTO1 “B” key (standard PC/SC-defined value),

Same value as the P1 parameter used in the LOAD KEY instruction: h00 or h20 (SpringCard
specific value).

The key index (byte 4) is defined as follow:

- If key type (byte 3) is h60, use values h00 to h03 to select one of the “A” keys stored in reader's
  volatile memory, and values h20 to h2F to select one of the “A” keys stored in reader's non-volatile memory (if available).
- If key type (byte 3) is h61, use values h00 to h03 to select one of the “B” keys stored in reader's
  volatile memory, and values h20 to h2F to select one of the “B” keys stored in reader's non-volatile memory (if available).

---

```
int PCSC_Mifare_Read (unsigned char *data, unsigned int read_size, unsigned char block_num)
{
  unsigned char TxBuffer[5]= {0xFF, 0xB0};
  unsigned char RxBuffer[42]= {0};
  int Response = -1;
  int SendLength = 0;
  unsigned long RecvLength = 0;

  if (data == NULL)
  {
        Debug(__func__,"Invalid Param");
    return Response;
  }

  if (0xFF > block_num)
  {
    TxBuffer[2] = 0x00;
    TxBuffer[3] = block_num;
  }
  else
  {
    /* If the block number is greater than 0xFF then store the block number's MSB in P1 field
       and LSB in P2 field of APDU*/
    TxBuffer[2] = (block_num % 0xFF);
    TxBuffer[3] = 0xFF;
  }

  TxBuffer[4] = read_size; //or 0x00 or 0x20 if card supports 32 BYTE data read

  SendLength = sizeof (TxBuffer);
  RecvLength = sizeof (RxBuffer);

  Response = SCardTransmit(hCard, pioSendPci, TxBuffer, SendLength,
                           &pioRecvPci, RxBuffer, &RecvLength);
  if (Response != SCARD_S_SUCCESS)
  {
    Debug (__func__,"SCardTransmit Failed: %s 0x%x",pcsc_stringify_error(Response), Response);
    return Response;
  }

  if ((RxBuffer[RecvLength-2] == 0x90) && (RxBuffer[RecvLength-1] == 0x00))
  {
    Debug (__func__,"Succeeded : %02x %02x",RxBuffer[RecvLength-2], RxBuffer[RecvLength-1]);

    if (RecvLength > 0x02)
    {
        memcpy (data, RxBuffer, (RecvLength-2));
                Debug(__func__,"Read passed");
    }
    else
    {
                Debug(__func__,"Read Failed");
                return -1;
    }
  }
  else
  {
     Debug(__func__,"Failed : %02x %02x",RxBuffer[RecvLength-2], RxBuffer[RecvLength-1]);
     return -1;
  }

  return Response;
}


int PCSC_Mifare_Write (unsigned char block_num, unsigned char *data,unsigned int size)
{
  unsigned char TxBuffer[21] = {0xFF, 0xD6};
  unsigned char RxBuffer[2] = {0};
  int Response = -1;
  int SendLength = 0;
  unsigned long RecvLength = 0;

  if (0xFF > block_num)
  {
    TxBuffer[2] = 0x00;
    TxBuffer[3] = block_num;
  }
  else
  {
    /* If the block number is greater than 0xFF then store the block number's MSB in P1 field
       and LSB in P2 field of APDU*/
    TxBuffer[2] = (block_num % 0xFF);
    TxBuffer[3] = 0xFF;
  }

  TxBuffer[4] = size; //This is the block size to be written

  //copy the 0x08 BYTE data to be writen to the card
  memcpy ((TxBuffer + 5), data, size);

  SendLength = 5+size;//sizeof (TxBuffer);
  RecvLength = sizeof (RxBuffer);

//  HexDump("PCSC_Mifare_Write", TxBuffer, SendLength);

  Response = SCardTransmit(hCard, pioSendPci, TxBuffer, SendLength,
                           &pioRecvPci, RxBuffer, &RecvLength);
  if (Response != SCARD_S_SUCCESS)
  {
    Debug (__func__,"SCardTransmit Failed: %s 0x%x",pcsc_stringify_error(Response), Response);
    return Response;
  }

  if ((RxBuffer[0] == 0x90) && (RxBuffer[1] == 0x00))
  {
    Debug (__func__,"Succeeded : %02x %02x",RxBuffer[0],RxBuffer[1]);
  }
  else
  {
    Debug (__func__,"Failed : %02x %02x",RxBuffer[0],RxBuffer[1]);
    return -1;
  }

  return Response;
}
```

Comment: i tried with same command. i am getting the response as 6E00..why i read lots of documentation..but same response i am getting

Comment: what exactly u want to do with your application u r making is that u want to read the sectors of the card and write some data according to the access conditions u r using ....

Comment: i want to read also from the card. and write data to the card also

Comment: kk ,this all u can do with an android application called "MIFARE CLASSIC TOOL" is there any NFC supported phone u r having if having then activate NFC on yr phone then put a MIFARE card back to u yr phone ,then the card will be detected by NFC reader in yr phone and in tht application u can read, write etc everything whatever u want.

Comment: even though if u want to make application to write or reading the sectors of the MIFARE smartcard then use PCSC commands and ADPU commands , i have make the same application it is reading and writing both by using these commands a program in c .

Comment: C code only i want... i am not working on the android application. its terminal application